# how to capture events from dynamically added layouts in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my android project, I need to add controls dynamically into my main activity screen. I created one xml (row.xml) which is added on button click on main screen. I want to capture events from the controls (button) given in row.xml.

Can anybody help me where and how to capture onClick events from newly added layouts?

Also, I want to add many child layout elements, do I need to write separate onClick methods for all the child views added dynamically?

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_Time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_FromTime"
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="@string/hintFromTime" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btnDelete" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, when I click on Add Time slot button, I get a newly created row with two elements.

I want to delete this row when I click on Delete button. Do I need to have a viewID also to delete this newly-added-view?

Answer (score 0):

Create an onclicklistener in the list adapter and set it to the buttons in the getView method of the adapter. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of your controls as Java variables - don't worry about dynamic android xml. Consider declaring them all at the top, outside of methods.

One way to avoid adding a new `OnClickListener` for each control is let your class implement `OnClickListener` then use `view.setOnClickListener(this)`. Alternatively create a subclass which overrides `onClick(View)` and use `setOnClickListener(MyListener)`.

You can use `Layout.removeView(View)` to remove controls, as long as you keep track of them.